# React.js indefinitely increasing table row count with each render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table component, to which I pass the rows, headings, current page, page size, etc.
I'm passing data to this component as an array of arrays, each subArray being a row. Now, I'm using this component such that I append fresh data(new arrays/new rows) at the start main array every 10 seconds. However, the issue is that every time I change the currentPage prop(change page from the pagination component, which simply changes one state and works as far as I can tell), the same fresh data rows are appended at the start of each page.

This is my code for the records component:

```js
const Records = ({headings, data, currentPage, recordsPerPage, onRowClick, skipIndexArray}) => {
    if(!data || !data.length) return (<h2>No data found.</h2>)
    // console.log(data.slice((currentPage - 1) * recordsPerPage, currentPage * recordsPerPage).length)
    return (  
        <table className="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover container py-3">
            <thead>
                <tr className="table-row">
                    {headings.map( (element, index) => <th key={index} className="text-center table-cell">{element}</th>)}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="myTable">
                { data.slice((currentPage - 1) * recordsPerPage, currentPage * recordsPerPage)
                    .map((element, index)=>{
                        console.log("ROW", index, "PAGE", currentPage)
                        return (
                            <tr className="table-row" key={element[0]} onClick={()=>{onRowClick(element)}}>
                                { element.map(subElement => <td>{subElement}</td>)
                                }
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    ) 
}
```

Parent relevant logic:

```js
    const [doubts, setDoubts] = useState([]);
    const [nPages, setNPages] = useState(1);
    const recordsPerPage = 5;

    useEffect(()=>{
        async function asyncUseEffect(){
            const response = await axios({...})
            setDoubts((oldDoubts)=>{
                const newData = [...response.data.map((element)=>{
                    return [element.a, element.b, element.c, element.d, element.e,
                            element.f, element.g];
                }), ...oldDoubts];
                setNPages(Math.ceil(newData.length / recordsPerPage));
                return newData;
            });
        }
        asyncUseEffect(callTime);
        const refreshClassesInterval = setInterval(asyncUseEffect, intervalMs);
        
        return () => clearInterval(refreshClassesInterval);
    }, []);


...

<Records headings={["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]} data={doubts}
currentPage={currentPage} recordsPerPage={recordsPerPage} onRowClick={()=>{}}
skipIndexArray={[]}/>
...
```

The console.log does log 5 as the array length each render, but I cannot tell why the number of rows is actually increasing with each render. Is the map method here not 'remaking' my entire row array again? If the length is 5, I should only have 5 rows.
I'm fairly new to React.js, but I can't tell why this is happening at all, any help is much appreciated. I suspect it has something to do with me not changing the page number with new data, but not only can I not change the page number with ever call, I'm already slicing the data to show the correct data for that page, so I'm really lost. Thanks!

Comment: Please also post the parent component/the one responsible for the props

Comment: Have you found the cause of the problem and a solution? If so, can you share the solution?